# Animate scaleX of rotated div

Tags: jquery, html, css, gsap

I have a rotated div that is longer than the viewport to cover the screen. I used the following code to center the div:

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left:-25%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150%;
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg);
    background: red;
}
```

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/9b8uLgw5/

When I try to animate the scaleX of that div using TweenLite, the div is off centered. I have tried using transformOrigin, but is does not seem to work for me.

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/85s1hrfo/1/

Comment: if you remove the `transformOrigin` property, does it not produce your desired result? what is the outcome you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the div to animate across the screen in the original position (centered). Removing transformOrigin still leaves the div uncentered.

Comment: so the part of that div is clipping and going past the top border of the viewport is the problem? like the animation flows from top to bottom? i am sorry, i am having a hard time visualising what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I had to set the `transform-origin`, `top`, and `right` properties properly.

```
right: 0;
top: -50%;
transform-origin: right center;
```

Then I calculated the angle from the top right corner of the div to the bottom left in order to get a proper transform angle.

```
var tAngle = -1 * Math.atan($('div.container').height()/$('div.container').width())*180/Math.PI)
$('div.bg').css({
    'transform': 'rotate(' + tAngle + 'deg)'
})
```

JS Fiddle with the solution here (scale the result pane and re-run to see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/85s1hrfo/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/n3fdnqhg/3/)** anywhere near your desired outcome?

***Snippet:***

```js
var myDIV = document.querySelector('div');
TweenLite.set(myDIV, {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '50%',
    top: '50%',
    width: '150%',
    height: '100%',
    xPercent: -50,
    yPercent: -125,
    transformOrigin: '100% 100%',
    rotation: -75
});
TweenLite.fromTo(myDIV, 1, { scaleX: 0 }, { scaleX: 1 });
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps in some way though.

Comment: No. I want that div to start out of the viewport and scale past the other side. The tween isn't the issue. It's getting the div to be centered in the viewport while the tween is happening.

Comment: you need to explain a bit more in detail. perhaps use drawings?